# struct as a parameter in C++

Tags: c++, parameters, struct

I'm a beginner so please keep it simple.

Anyway, I have a struct defined like so:

```
struct card      
  {
  char rank[10];
  char suit[10];
  char color;
  bool dealt;
  char location[10];
  };
```

and I have a function that is passed this type of struct:

```
  void importCard(card deck[52]);
```

The problem is, if I define the struct in main(), then the compiler does not know what "card" is at the time of function declaration (above main). How do I get around this without defining the struct as a global?

Comment: When you say "I define the struct in main()", do you mean you do something like `card c;`?

Answer (score 5):

It's fine to define *types* as "globals", so just define the `struct` type at the top of the file.

---

By the way, note that the delaration

```
void importCard(card deck[52]);
```

is almost never written that way, because the compiler just discards the `52` in there (so that having it in the source code is a bit misleading).

Instead it's written as e.g.

```
void importCard(card deck[]);
```

And to be thorough I should mention that the coding gets a lot easier by using `std::vector` instead of raw arrays, and then the function would be e.g.

```
vector<card> importCards();
```

Comment: Was just about to write that - too slow again! ;)

Comment: I guess that was pretty obvious. My teacher said no global variables but I think a struct definition falls under a different category... thanks :)

Comment: @user1362548 it is a different category, yes.  Declaring the `struct` does not create an instance of it, so it's not a "global variable".